# How do I change the date format depending on Start and End date in Drupal 7

Tags: views, entities, datetime

I have a content type called 'Events' including the fields:

- Title
- Thumbnail
- Date (Can be a start, or both a start and end date)

I have created a view that takes this content type and outputs it as follows:

- Exhibition
- Thumbnail
- 17 December 2015 or 17 December 2015 - 23 December 2015

My question is how can I can change the output of the field if the 'Date' field has a start date and an end date.

I am using the Event Calendar Module to create my events.

Can you offer a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would help if you show an example of desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the **Date Views** module

In views, click on your field and change Date Format to Custom

For Custom Date Format: you can put something like this `m/d/y`  or `M d, Y`

You can format it however you want by using the format characters from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[image]